# Read multiple files but keep track of which file is which dataframe in R

Tags: r, lapply

Let's say I have these files:

```
N1.xlsx
N2.xlsx
N3.xlsx
N4.xlsx
```

I want them in a list, but each dataframe must be named according to the file it was read from, like

```
mylist = 
N1
N2
N3
N4
```

I'm using:

```
fnames =  mixedsort(sort(list.files("filepath", pattern = '*.xlsx', full.names = F)))

mylist <- lapply(fnames, function(x) {
 read_xlsx(paste0(x),  col_names = TRUE)
})
```

But this code creates a list without identification

```
mylist = 
[[1]]
[[2]]
[[3]]
[[4]]
```

Its important to keep the names of each file in each dataframe, so I can export them correctly later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy could be to make *fnames* without extension first, then `paste0` the extension in the `lapply` with the advantage that you can use *fnames* to `setNames`.

```
fnames <- gtools::mixedsort(gsub(".xlsx", "", list.files("filepath", pattern="*.xlsx")))
mylist <- setNames(lapply(fnames, function(x)
  openxlsx::read.xlsx(paste0("filepath/", x, ".xlsx"))), fnames)
# $N1
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
# 
# $N2
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
# 
# $N3
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
# 
# $N4
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
```

*Note:* I used `openxlsx::read.xlsx` since you didn't reference your `library` that `read_xlsx` stems from, but this should work the same way with it.

---

*Data:*

```
N1 <- N2 <- N3 <- N4 <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
sapply(ls(pattern="^N"), function(p) 
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(mget(p, envir=.GlobalEnv), paste0("filepath/", p, ".xlsx")))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called [libr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/libr/index.html) that does exactly what you are asking for. You can do it in one line of code. The syntax is this:

```
libname(mylist, "<path to files>", "xlsx")
```

Above code will put the data in the variable `mylist`, with each dataset named according to the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

if you try your code:

```
fnames =  mixedsort(sort(list.files("filepath", pattern = '*.xlsx', full.names = F)))

mylist <- lapply(fnames, function(x) {
 read_xlsx(paste0(x),  col_names = TRUE)
})
```

followed by a function to rename list elements?

```
names(mylist)<-str_remove(fnames, '.xlsx')
```

Another option would be to include the renaming step into the function that creates the list:

```
fnames =  mixedsort(sort(list.files("filepath", pattern = '*.xlsx', full.names = F)))

create_list<-function(fnames){
mylist<-lapply(fnames, function(x) {
 read_xlsx(paste0(x),  col_names = TRUE)
})
names(mylist)<-str_remove(fnames, '.xlsx')
}

create_list(fnames)
```

example of the first strategy:

```
mylist<-list(c(1:4), c(1:5), c('a','b'), c('d','e','f'))
fnames<-c("N1.xlsx","N2.xlsx","N3.xlsx","N4.xlsx")

names(mylist)<-str_remove(fnames, '.xlsx')

> mylist
$N1
[1] 1 2 3 4

$N2
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$N3
[1] "a" "b"

$N4
[1] "d" "e" "f"
```

Comment: For some reason your code is changing all the collumns to a collumn named N1 N2 etc, instead of renaming the dataframe list. If you make it functional, it might be a very good code because we can rename the dataframes by using str_remove!

Comment: Sorry for that, @GabrielG. I think it is ok now

Answer (score 1):

You could name `mylist` with the names you already have in `fnames`.

```
names(mylist) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(fnames)
mylist
```

`file_path_sans_ext` remove extension from the filenames.

If you want to  rename anything in the file name (for example N1 any  text.xlsx), you could use

```
names(mylist) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(str_remove(fnames, " any  text"))
mylist
```

Or even:

```
names(mylist) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(str_replace(fnames, " any  text", "other text"))
mylist
```